# Password Strength Calculation In Mobile/Web Applications

Tags: android, passwords, mobile-development

Is there any common convention, API/Library or Algorithm for password strength calculation in mobile/web applications for displaying  the words: "Weak", "Medium" etc...  or everyone is implementing this differently?

Comment: Can check this question from leetcode, there are many discussions which may help. https://leetcode.com/problems/strong-password-checker/

Comment: They're all doing it differently.  There's no definite meaning for "weak", "medium", etc.  There's probably a couple of libraries that are popular, but there's no solid definition